# Deploy MobileFirst hybrid application in Google Appengine

Tags: android, angularjs, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to MobileFirst(earlier IBM Worklight) development which focuses on developing Hybrid mobile applications for Android, ios and other platforms.

I use MobileFirst 6.3.0 plugin with Eclipse IDE. I have my MobileFirst project built and running in Android simulator in my local system. I want to deploy the hybrid application in Google app engine (preferably through Eclipse plugin) so that I can access the mobile application from anywhere. I couldn't find suitable tutorial for the same in internet.

Is there anyone to help me out in this regard?

Comment: Actually this is a business requirement to use MobileFirst

Comment: The more precise you can question the better the answer will be. In your question you present a whole workflow; a small book could be written about that. I recommend you start trying out what you are trying to do and then ask one question about exactly that. Then repeat until your goal is reached.

Comment: Does your question mean that from the MobileFirst application you would want to consume services hosted on Google app engine?

Comment: I'm sorry,I couldn't make you understand my point.Few rest services are already built and hosted somewhere else,these are managed by some other team.My MobileFirst application would call those rest services to get JSON output to display it on the html view.I've used AngularJS, Bootstrap to design the hybrid application which is running fine in my local system.I've exported apk to install the application in Android phone.Now this app is not working in Android as local system server is not up (server is stopped).I want to deploy this MobileFirst application in GAE so that it works in Android too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot deploy the application to Google Appengine.  You need an environment where you can install Tomcat, WebSphere full profile or WebSphere Liberty profile, on top of which you must install MobileFirst Server (which you must buy for commercial use). For this you can use either bare metal (your own installment), or Bluemix and other services, perhaps AWS.